# MYSQL UPDATE incorrect syntax?

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with a simple update command to a row in a table called `lychee_settings`, table description is:-

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| key   | varchar(50)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| value | varchar(200) | YES  |     |         |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

row I want to change is (0 to 1):-

```
| skipDuplicates  | 0                                                            |
```

I am running

```
UPDATE lychee_settings SET value = '1' WHERE key = 'skipDuplicates';
```

which returns an

> You have an error in your SQL syntax.

I can't see what I am doing wrong, must be something very simple, any help much appreciated!

Comment: PLEASE.... always show us ALL the error message not a sub set of the error message

Comment: Most probably 'key' is the issue (reserved word). Change it to \`key\` (in backsticks).

Comment: Excellent, that was it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word in MySQL so if you have to use it as a column name (not recommended) you have to wrap that column name is backticks.

```
UPDATE lychee_settings SET value = '1' WHERE `key` = 'skipDuplicates';
```